# Twitch трансляция

Tags: php, javascript, twitch

Как добавить twitch трансляцию на свой сайт?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `iframe`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML:**

```
<iframe 
  src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=название канала" 
  frameborder="0" 
  allowfullscreen="true" 
  scrolling="no" 
  height="378" 
  width="620">
</iframe>
```

Так же можно добавить чат:

```
<iframe 
  src="https://www.twitch.tv/название канала/chat?popout=" 
  frameborder="0" 
  scrolling="no" 
  height="500" 
  width="350">
</iframe>
```